# ES6+ export of an import within export default

Tags: ecmascript-6, import, export

I'm trying to do this

**state.js**

```
export default {
  someValue: 'fooBar'
}
```

**index.js**

```
export default {
  export {default as state} from './state',
  export {default as actions} from './actions'
}
```

but I am not allowed, `Unexpected keyword 'export' (2:2)`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? A nested `export` doesn’t make any sense, since `export` is not an expression.

Comment: I'm just trying to eliminate an import line `import state from './state'` where I then `export default { state }` it

Comment: I think you might be looking for [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports), but the browser support is currently limited to pre-release builds of browsers. Even with those, you still don’t get the exported values, but a Promise holding them.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `import` and `export` at the top level of your module. (You can use dynamic `import()` elsewhere, but not the static versions.)

So to have that export, you have to do what you've said you're trying to avoid in the comments:

```
import {default as state} from './state';
import {default as actions} from './actions';
export default {
  state, actions
};
```

**but**, beware what you're exporting there: an object with `state` and `actions` properties whose **initial values** come from the imported `state` and `action`, but which are **not** connected to them. Code importing that object can change those properties. You could maintain the live binding:

```
import {default as state} from './state';
import {default as actions} from './actions';
export default {
  get state() {
    return state;
  },
  get actions() {
    return actions;
  }
};
```

but at that point you're kind of reinventing the module namespace object. You might prefer to simply:

```
export {default as state} from './state.js';
export {default as actions} from './actions.js';
```

and then either use those named exports:

```
import {state, actions} from "./index";
```

or use the module namespace object

```
import * as index from "./index";
// Use `index.state` and `index.actions`
```